# Unable to install GATE software using "make install" command - "-- Up-to-date:" related error

Tags: permissions, executable, cmake, execute-command

I am installing GATE 8.2 (a Geant4 based software) on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 system, following instructions given in GATE website. Everything works fine but in last stage of the GATE software can't be installed as `make install` command give error (?) like this:

```
[  4%] Built target MetaIO
[  6%] Built target itkzlib
[100%] Built target Gate

Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /home/sghosh/Documents/Satyajit/softwares/GATE/gate_v8.2-install/bin/Gate
```

I think it can be a silly mistake that I am doing and related to basics of CMake-based installation in Linux based machine.

Interestingly the file `Gate` in above mentioned folder (`/home/sghosh/Documents/Satyajit/softwares/GATE/gate_v8.2-install/bin/`) looks like text file although it should be an executable and hence should look like violet color icon (according to ubuntu 18.04.3 norm). But as I found out that c++ executables are also looks text file and I have do `chmod 755 a.out` on those to make it run. I have tried to do `chmod` on `Gate` executable also but without any success.

Comment: What happens when you try `/home/sghosh/Documents/Satyajit/softwares/GATE/gate_v8.2-install/bin/Gate` in a terminal? What does `file /home/sghosh/Documents/Satyajit/softwares/GATE/gate_v8.2-install/bin/Gate` return?

Comment: Great! It gives correct terminal outputs when GATE runs from terminal successfully. Moreso, I am abel to run my simulation macro file succesfully after putting the file in that folder and running from there. Is this mean that the software has installed suceessfully? Although there are environment configuration steps needed to be completed. Could you explain the whole process in a form of complete answer post, I will be glade. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it actually prints any errors. It simply prints the path to the binary:

```
-- Up-to-date: /home/sghosh/Documents/Satyajit/softwares/GATE/gate_v8.2-install/bin/Gate
```

You can execute this from terminal with simply entering `/home/sghosh/Documents/Satyajit/softwares/GATE/gate_v8.2-install/bin/Gate`